# reactjs - How to render a component which render return a component?

Tags: reactjs

for the following example I have a component `GetCurrentVisitor` which renders `Visitors`.

However it will only render the `<h1>` tag and the table is empty. I suspect I need to use `ReactDOM` to render `Vistors` component as well. But how to do it?

```
var VISITORS = [
        {
            first_name: 'Harry',
            last_name: 'Potter'
        },
        {
            first_name: 'Hermione',
            last_name: 'Granger'
        }
    ]

class GetCurrentVisitors extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visitors: VISITORS
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Current visitors</h1>
                <Visitors visitors={this.state.visitors} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Visitors extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <table>
                {this.props.visitors.forEach(
                    function(visitor) {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            {console.log('from: ', visitor.first_name)}
                            {visitor.first_name}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    })}
            </table>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <GetCurrentVisitors />, document.getElementById('getcurrentvisitors'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you should use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
{this.props.visitors.map(function(visitor, index) {
  return <tr key={index}>
    <td>{ visitor.first_name } </td>
  </tr>
})}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/34261/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also are able to use `.forEach` but in another way [***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/321/)

```
render () {
  let itemList = [];
  this.props.visitors.forEach(function(visitor,index) {
    itemList.push(<tr key={index}><td>
        {visitor.first_name}
      </td></tr>
    )
  })
  return (
    <table>
      {itemList}
    </table>
    );
}
```

As for me `Array.prototype.map` more easy to use with React. It just another example.

Thanks